# How to call ICommand from DataTemplate Model Class

Tags: xaml, mvvm, icommand

I am building an application in MVVM pattern. I have two classes SettingsDesignerItemViewModel & SettingsDesignerItem. I implemented ICommand in the ViewModel, but I want to use it in SettingsDesignerItem. How to call ICommand from SettingsDesignerItem.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CampaignStudio">

    <x:Array x:Key="CriteriaTypeList" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString CriteriaString = "SELECT"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString CriteriaString = "SINGLE"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString CriteriaString = "MULTIPLE"/>
    </x:Array>

    <x:Array x:Key="ConditionList" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ConditionString = "SELECT"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ConditionString = "AND"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ConditionString = "OR"/>
    </x:Array>

    <x:Array x:Key="OperatorList" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "SELECT"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "LESS THAN"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "LESS THAN OR EQUAL"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "GREATER THAN"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "GREATER THAN OR EQUAL"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "EQUAL"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString OperatorString = "NOT EQUAL"/>
    </x:Array>

    <x:Array x:Key="TargetCriteriaRuleList" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString TargetCriteriaRuleString = "SELECT"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString TargetCriteriaRuleString = "SELECT CUSTOMER WHERE ANY VALUES MEET THESE CRITERIA"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString TargetCriteriaRuleString = "CREATE SUPPRESSION FLAG BASED ON CRITERIA"/>
    </x:Array>

    <!-- DataTemplate for DesignerCanvas look and feel -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsDesignerItemViewModel}">
            <Grid>
            <Image IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    Stretch="Fill"
                    Source="../../Images/TargetCriteria.png"
                    Tag="TargetCriteria" />
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="5"
                    Template="{StaticResource infoButtonTemplate}"
                    Command="{Binding ShowDataChangeWindowCommand}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- DataTemplate for Popup look and feel -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsDesignerItemData}">
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid Name="CriteriaGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="383" Width="900" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" FontSize="13" CanUserAddRows="True" ColumnHeaderHeight="40" RowHeight="30" ItemsSource="{Binding TargetCriteriaList}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CriteriaType" Width="1*" ItemsSource="{StaticResource CriteriaTypeList}" DisplayMemberPath ="CriteriaString"  SelectedValuePath="CriteriaString" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding CriteriaType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Priority" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Priority, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Condition" Width="1*" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ConditionList}" DisplayMemberPath ="ConditionString"  SelectedValuePath="ConditionString" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Condition, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="[" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding OpenBracket, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data Item" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding DataItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Operator" Width="2*" ItemsSource="{StaticResource OperatorList}" DisplayMemberPath ="OperatorString"  SelectedValuePath="OperatorString" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Operator, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Values" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Values, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="]" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding CloseBracket, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Label Content="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="121,37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TargetCriteriaName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="799"/>
            <Label Content="Description:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="121,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TargetCriteriaDesc}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="799"/>
            <Label Content="Criteria:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,167,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label Content="Rule:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,601,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,605,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="567" ItemsSource="{StaticResource TargetCriteriaRuleList}" DisplayMemberPath="TargetCriteriaRuleString" SelectedIndex="{Binding TargetCriteriaRule}"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="933,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="-2.821,1.96">
                <Image Source="../../Images/RowAdd.png"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="934,236,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Height="30" RenderTransformOrigin="-2.821,1.96">
            <Image Source="../../Images/RowDelete.png"></Image>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to trigger a command on the ViewModel `SettingsDesignerItemViewModel` from the model `SettingsDesignerItem`? You shouldn't do that, as it violates the separation of concerns for which MVVM is designed. The model is agnostic of the ViewModel. The typical design for your requirement would be:

The ViewModel holds a command, which calls a function on the model. If you want to trigger this function from the model rather than the ViewModel, the model can just call it's own function. Rather than notifying the ViewModel that the *method has been executed*, you should use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICollectionChanged` to notify the ViewModel of the changes in the *properties that were affected by the execution of the method*.